# Something like python's __init__ in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

Is there something like `__init__` in C++?

Python let me pass arguments to class easily with `__init__`.

Like This:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    
    def printData(self):
        print(f"Title: {self.title}")
        print(f"Author: {self.author}")

book1 = Book("The C++ Programming Language", "Bjarne Stroustrup")
book1.printData()

############### Result ###############
# Title: The C++ Programming Language
# Author: Bjarne Stroustrup
```

But I want to do it in C++

Is there a solution in this kind of way?:

```
#include <string>

class Book {  
   public:  
      void something_like_init(title, author) {
          std::string title = title;
          std::string author = author;
      }   
};
```

Comment: That `__init__` thing is called a constructor in C++. Please have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/)

Comment: Also read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-c/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the constructor of classes in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Book {
  std::string private_variable;

public:
  // Equivalent to __init__ (it's what you're asking)
  Book(std::string value) {
    private_variable = value;
    ...
  }
  printVariable() {
    std::cout << private_variable << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use list initialization method:

```
Book(std::string value) : private_variable(value) {
  ...
}
```

Note that the constructor is only called when you create an instance of the class, for example:

```
int main(void) {
  Book book("Hello");
  book.printVariable(); // Will display --> Hello
  ...
}
```